# Edit TinyMCE style options

Tags: tinymce

On a form, I work with TinyMCE for editing textarea's.
Now I just want to offer the options "bold", "italic" and "underline" in TinyMCE.
Which settings should I do in the tinymce.init();?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the tinymce fiddle [here](http://fiddle.tinymce.com/PGeaab/1).

Here is the code:

```
tinymce.init({
    selector: "textarea",             // change textareas into tinymce editors
    plugins: [],                      // no additional plugins needed
    toolbar: "bold italic underline", // only those three buttons
    menubar: false                    // no display of the top menubar
});
```

Comment: @JasperPoppe: in that case you should accept the answer :)